# using regex replace in node js

Tags: node.js, regexp-replace

I'm trying to build a regex using 2 variables read from other application, the replace is in this case 'new line'. Search-part works as expected thow replaces as text '\n' instead of a new line

```
var replaceWith = ("'")+\n+("'");
var Search = -_-
var result = str.replace( new RegExp( Search, 'g' ), replaceWith);
    fs.writeFile(jobPath, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
```

await job.sendToData(Connection.Level.Success);

*Original text:*
Publication-_-PublicationDate

*I get result: *
Publication\nPublicationDate

*I need:*
Publication
PublicationDate

Comment: You get a result? That sounds pretty unlikely given that both `var replaceWith = ("'")+\n+("'");` and `var Search = -_-` are illegal syntax and will throw an error when you try to run it. Also, note that in modern JS you want `let` for reassignable variables and `const` for set-once variables. `var` is the original and now legacy keyword that creates variables with highly unusual (to most people) scoping rules. If you're writing new code, don't use `var` anymore =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it looks like you're looking for is the following:

```js
const str = 'Publication-_-PublicationDate';
const replaceWith = ('\n');
const Search = '-_-';
const result = str.replace( new RegExp( Search, 'g' ), replaceWith);
console.log(result);
```

It could also be shortened to this:

```js
const str = 'Publication-_-PublicationDate';
const result = str.replace('-_-', '\n');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Correct, though when de variable 'const replaceWith = ('\n');' is read from a third party (Enfocus Switch using code: 'flowElement.getPropertyStringValue("Replace")')
 I get the value '\n' as text and is not applied as a linebreak (so result is textline: Publication\nPublicationDate).
Any idea on how I can fix this ?

Comment: What it sounds like is that you have a question better suited for the Enfocus community forum than StackOverflow as the problem you're having is more about how Enfocus Switch ingests data than writing the code to produce that data. As we both agree that this answer is correct as far as the regex is concerned though, please mark the answer as correct for people who find this in the future.

Comment: Many thanks Ryan, I'll post this on Enfocus Forum